# Does every ASP.NET Web Application has a Single Application Domain?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, iis

I am bit confused. Is there only one application domain for every single ASP.NET Web Application or there can be anywhere between 1 to 100 application domains present in a single application pool of a web application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An Application Domain is the logical and physical boundary created around every .NET application by the Common Language Runtime (CLR).

1. **One web application runs in a single Application Domain** but may communicate via web/remote services with applications in other domains.
2. **The CLR may allow multiple .NET applications to be run in a single Application Domain**, so it means that an Application Domain may be shared by different applications which can in that case communicate with each other "directly".

Most times though, the relationship between a web application and an application domain is one-to-one.

You may read the following article (very short, but nicely written) which explains what are Application Domains and how they may be useful: http://www.beansoftware.com/NET-Tutorials/Application-Domain.aspx.

Also, on his [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2007/09/02/application-vs-appdomain.aspx), Scott Forsyth explains the differences between an application (IIS term), a web application (ASP.NET term) and application domains.